# How to draw this box and insert it into my code with the perpendicular symbol?

Tags: tabularx

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.8\linewidth}|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Tabela 2: Uma organização hiperdimensional multinível (HDML) consistindo de 20 intersecções entre as dimensões e níveis de responder relacional arbitrariamente aplicável combinados com as dimensões de orientação e evocação de modelo DAARE.} \\
\hline
Dimensões & Níveis & Coerência & Complexidade & Derivação & Flexibilidade \\
\hline
Implicar Mutualmente & Unidade Analítica 1 & Unidade Analítica 2 & $\bot$ & $\bot$ \\
\hline
Emoldurar Relacional & $\bot$ & $\bot$ & $\bot$ & $\bot$ \\
\hline
Reticular Relacional & $\bot$ & $\bot$ & $\bot$ & $\bot$ \\
\hline
Relacionar Relações & $\bot$ & $\bot$ & $\bot$ & $\bot$ \\
\hline
Relacionar Redes Relacionais & $\bot$ & $\bot$ & $\bot$ & Unidade Analítica 20 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what you want to do. Do you want to re-create the photo exactly? If so, your example code seems to be doing something different.

Comment: provided MWE is not close to showed image. However, it can be written with much shorten code: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{|*{5}{c|}}    \hline
\bot & \bot & \bot & \bot & \bot \\ \hline
\bot & \bot & \bot & \bot & \bot \\ \hline
\bot & \bot & \bot & \bot & \bot \\ \hline
\bot & \bot & \bot & \bot & \bot \\ \hline
\bot & \bot & \bot & \bot & \bot \\ \hline
\bot & \bot & \bot & \bot & \bot \\ \hline
\bot & \bot & \bot & \bot & \bot \\ \hline
\bot & \bot & \bot & \bot & \bot \\ \hline
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}`.

Comment: For shape shown on image see Ti*k*Z Library `shapes.callouts`.

Comment: I would like to create that box with the perpendicular symbol inside.